# IndexError using pandas from_dict

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

When constructing dataframe from a dict, the following example, throws an IndexError(index out of bounds).

```
import pandas as pd
d = {(0,1):{1:'a'}}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index')
```

If I modify the dict as below, there is no index error

```
import pandas as pd
d = {1:{1:'a'}}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index')
```

Why does a tuple as the dict key cause the IndexError?

Comment: The 1st ex works as expected on v0.15.1

Comment: I am using 0.14.1. Time to update! Could you please post an answer? I will accept it.

Comment: Feel free to accept unutbu's a. S/he's more knowlegeable than me anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your version of Pandas. In version 0.15.2, `from_dict` works as expected:

```
In [18]: pd.__version__
Out[20]: '0.15.2-113-g5531341'

In [14]: d = {(0,1):{1:'a'}}

In [15]: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index')
Out[15]: 
     1
0 1  a

In [16]: d = {1:{1:'a'}}

In [17]: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index')
Out[17]: 
   1
1  a
```